# How can I stop a MouseEvent in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

(Sorry for my poor English)

I don't know how I can stop a Mouse Event in JavaFX.

This code generates a small image into a large rectangle when I press a button and then pressed the large rectangle, but if I press again the big rectangle is rebuilt a new image.

I dont want to generate a new image, how Can I do that?

```
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
        rectangle.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) -> {

            Rectangle asdf = new Rectangle(48, 48, Color.TRANSPARENT);

            StackPane imageContainer = new StackPane();
            ImageView image = new ImageView("firefox-icono-8422-48.png");
            imageContainer.getChildren().addAll(asdf, image);
            imageContainer.setTranslateX(me.getX());
            imageContainer.setTranslateY(me.getY());

            enableDragging(imageContainer);

            rootGroup.getChildren().add(imageContainer);
            myList2.add(imageContainer);

        });
    });
```

Thanks

PS: t.consume() and me.consume(); don't anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have interpreted your question correctly, but if you want to "turn off" the mouse click handler on the rectangle, you can just call

```
rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(null);
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ActivateRectangleWithButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(80, 80, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);

        StackPane stack = new StackPane(border, rect);

        Button button = new Button("Activate");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            border.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            rect.setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
                System.out.println("Active rectangle was clicked!");

                // de-activate:
                border.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                rect.setOnMouseClicked(null);
            });
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(20, stack, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```